# Why does my nickname command only accept one word Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Title says it all... I'm having trouble with my nickname command as it only changes the nickname to the first word written...
Code:

```
       module.exports = {
        name: "nickname",
        aliases: [],
        run: async (message, args, client) => {

            const nickname = message.mentions.members.first()
            const nick = args[1];
            nickname.setNickname(nick)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how `args` is constructed once it's passed into `run`. I'm assuming it separates the command string based on the spaces (eg. if you type `nickname The Person` it'll split it into an array with 3 elements `["nickname", "The", "Person"]`. If you don't have any more important arguments for this command you could just combine the split elements back into one string again.

```
let nick = "";

args.map((value, index) => {
    if (index !== 0) nick+=value+" ";
})
```

Or something like that

Comment: Using `args.slice(1).join(' ')` is much easier than a loop with `map()`

Comment: @NumberedBore7 You're welcome! Also, use Lioness100's alternative as it's more concise.